# Sum as function convergence

Tags: real-analysis

On principles of mathematical analysis by Rudin I found the following definition of point wise convergence:$f(x)=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x)$

If I take for example the function $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ it converges to 0 that is different of the sum $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$.

My point is: How can $f(x)=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x)$ instead of $f(x)=\lim_{i\to\infty}f_i(x)$? Once as my example corroborates $\lim_{i\to\infty}f_i(x)\neq\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(x)$.

What does Rudin mean?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n (x)=1/n $.

the sequence of functions $(f_n) $ is pointwise convergent to zero but it doesn't mean that the series of functions $\sum f_n(x) $ is convergent.

if it is the case, we can define the limit function $$f (x)=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f_i (x) $$

For example if you take $f_n (x)=1/n^2$,
then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f_i (x)=\pi^2/6$$

Comment: Considering your example $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n^2}$. If I take the limit which should be equal to $f(x)$ I get : $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=0\neq \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. How can $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f_i (x)=\pi^2/6$ be equal to $f(x)$? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @PedroGomes $0+0+0+.....=0.\infty $ is not always $=0$.

Comment: I cannot understand your reply. $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}f_i (x)=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}....$